# Login user without Capybara in request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec2

I'm developing a rails application and I'm following Michael Hartl's famous tutorial. I'm using newer versions of RSpec and Capybara and have therefore run into a problem. Since Capybara 2, you need to [place tests using Capybara in spec/features](http://www.andylindeman.com/2012/11/11/rspec-rails-and-capybara-2.0-what-you-need-to-know.html). RSpec Capybara [does no longer](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) work in request spec. The solution Hartl is giving is therefore no longer working (he is placing all his tests in spec/requests).

I need to login a user without Capybara in a request test (because the test uses the "put", which is only available in request specs). Others with the same problem seems to have solved it with:

```
post login_path(session: { password: user.password, email: user.email })
cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
```

but I get the error:

```
Failure/Error: before { valid_login_request(user) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'
 # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:13:in `valid_login_request'
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:22:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

and in sessions_controller.rb:7 is the following code:

```
 user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
```

After some research, I found that it's the session that's nil and that's why I get the "NoMethodError" above. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I moved to Hartl's new guide and there I found a way to authorize the user with both temporary and persistent cookies.